# Relationship between affine and linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that a function $f$ is linear if and only if $f$ is affine and $f(0) = 0$.

[Hint: First assume $f$ is linear, and show that $f$ is affine and $f(0) = 0$. Next assume that $f$ is affine and that $f(0) = 0$, and use this to show that $f$ respects vector addition and scalar multiplication.]

So I know that a linear function respects additivity and scalar multiplication and an affine function is a linear function plus a constant, but I don't understand how an affine function could ever map to $0$ unless the constant is $0$ thus making it linear. This proof seems self evident to some extent and so I don't know where to start (despite the hint) or how to prove it...

My first thought was to say:

A linear function respects additivity: $f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ and

A function is affine if: $f((1-t)u + tv) = (1-t)f(u) + tf(v)$, for $t$ in $[0,1]$

But since $t$ is a constant the one equation is basically the same as the other, so where to go from there? I think the biggest issue I'm having is that I have no experience working with mathematical proofs, or how to logically work through one.

Comment: You've got it. Your intuition is correct. This exercise is to practice proof writing, showing how hypotheses necessarily lead to conclusions. In this case, you have to prove in both directions: a statement and its converse.

Comment: Carefully write down what it means for a function $f$ to be linear and for a function $f$ to be affine. Then, use the properties of one definition to establish the properties of the other. Note that you must be as general as possible, making no *extra* assumptions about the function $f$.